# Pull-request on TFS (guarded) with checklist

Tags: tfs, pull-request

i am wondering if there is a way to incorporate a checklist in a pull-request.
The reviewer shall check some things mentioned on that checklist and enter some result, like 'done' or 'not applicable' or 'found an issue'.
It would be very nice if a not fully answered checklist could block a pull request.

A direct approach could be to paste the checklist as one or several comments.
This one seems tedious, and does not block the PR from completion...
Another approach could be to create a template work-item related to the pullrequest, containing the checklist, or one work-item for each entry in the checklist. Once again tedious and non blocking...

We are using:
Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 16.122.27409.2
--> TFS 2018 Update 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you are using TFS 2017 and later version, then you can achieve that by applying **Branch Policies**.

1. Navigate to Admin -> Version Control
   (`http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{Project}/_admin/_versioncontrol`)
2. Select the specific Repository and **Branch** --> Enable **Protect
   this branch** --> Enable **Check for comment resolution** -->
   **Required**
3. Create a pull request, paste the checklist as one or several
   comments, [Markdown is supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=vsts) for comments, you can copy the
   checklist like below format as a checkbox:

   ```
   - [ ] check 1
   - [ ] check 2
   ```

Thus the policy will block pull requests from being completed while any comments are **Active**. So, you can change the state of the checklist comments to **Closed** once they are all checked.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for pointing that out. I'll give it a shot.